# how to use rspec to post a json body to API

Tags: json, post, rspec

I am starting to write a test which is use rpsec to post a json body to API and checkout the response.

I searched a lot from web and I cannot find out which way is the most simple to do that.

For Example
I want to post a json body to https://my-web-site/notification
and checkout the respose is 201.

would you guys mind to help me to begin to first step.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a controller spec:

```
RSpec.describe NotificationController, :type => :controller do
  # If you want to inspect the response, include this
  # render_views

  it "sends JSON data" do
    post "/notification", foo: "bar", format: :json

    expect(response.status).to eq(201)
    # To examine the response:
    # response_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    # expect(response_json).to eq({some: :object})
  end
end
```

I'd recommend actually checking the body JSON response. Only testing the response code may not be all that meaningful.

Comment: thank you very much for answer it so soon.
sorry that I have no base knowlege, maybe the questions are very stupid.

do I have to write another spec to define class or something? 
where should I define the url?

thanks a lot

Comment: Sure, feel free to accept if it answers your question.

Comment: would you mind tell me where to define the url? and how should I define the NotifictionController? Thankyou

Comment: `NotificationController` is just an example, it's whatever the name of your controller is. The URL is whatever is specificed in your `routes.rb`

Comment: oh, I see.
I need to write a controller and routes.rb. I'll learn how to do it . 
Thankyou